# How to import another xcode project to Xcode with the same hierarchy?

Tags: xcode, import, project

I have some Xcode example which uses oxygine-sound library and works great. I want to include this library to my project too. But I can't to do it. In the example it looks like this:
[image]

but when I drag oxygine-sound.xcodeproj (I have this file downloaded) I get another picture of hierarchy. I can't create src folder inside that project or maybe I don't need to do it, I don't know. My attempt looks like this:
[image]

Why the example project hierarchy looks different from my attempt to make the same?

Answer (score 0):

It's an Xcode issue.

Just close the workspace what you are trying to import and drag and drop this project directly from its folder.